# Drop down list showing data from a SharePoint List using CAML SOAP Ajax JQuery methodology

Tags: jquery, soap, caml

I need to pull list items from a static list in SharePoint and have those list items displayed in a drop down list in my non-InfoPath custom form.  I can't use SPServices.  I need to the CAML-SOAP-Ajax-JQuery methodology.

Anyone's help is sooooo greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So if any of you venture pass this plea of desperation. I gave into SPServices method.  Resistance is futile:
Here's the link: http://www.sympraxisconsulting.com/Demos/Demo%20Pages/CascadingDropdowns.aspx

Good luck with your jquery journey.